# Problems when debugging in vscode Breakpoints are disabled

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I have a problem when starting the debug in vscode (F5) the Breakpoints are disabled, thus not making stops at the chosen locations. I've already changed the "webRoot" with or without a slash in launch.json, see below.

launch.json configuration

[image: launch.json configuration]

Before starting the debug:

[image: Before starting the debug.]

When starting Debug:

[image: When starting Debug.]

When starting the debug where the breakpoints are disabled

I also changed the sourceMap in `Tsconfig.json` to true and then false to see if it worked and nothing.

I would like to know if anyone has experienced this and if they have a solution and why this happen

Answer (score 0):

This item was resolved as follows by adding this item "start": "ng serve --host=127.0.0.1" in package.json. Now I'm trying to understand what happens to the error Unexpected 503 response from http://127.0.0.1:4200/runtime.js.map: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same issue with a react app. whenever i start my debugger with active breakpoints debugger just hangs, but it runs fine without them or if they are disabled

Answer (score 0):

We have been facing a similar issue for the past few days. If we start our React application in debug, with active breakpoints, the debugger hangs and we need to stop the debugger, clear all the break points and start the debugger again (in order to have it working).

Answer (score 0):

It was occurred with me too. I guess I was using two debugger extensions at the same time. I fixed this by disabling PHP Devsense and keeping only PHP Debug, and it worked!